# Cider fermentation stopped (or very slow)

Tags: cider

I've brewed a bunch of ciders, all starting at OG about 1.060.  I've always fermented with Safale S-04.  2 packets for 5-6 gallons of cider.  Usually ferments for about 7-10 days.
I'm now making a cider with an OG of 1.087.  I pitched the same 2 packets of yeast.  There was active fermentation at about 65F for over 1 week, starting 11/23/2015.  Sometime later, it slowed down and I figured it was nearly complete at 62F.  Current gravity on 12/13/2015 is 1.050!  I'm wondering if the S-04 is not going to cut it for this high gravity cider.  I'm considering pitching champagne yeast or Wyeast 4766 (which I've just discovered now).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

62F is a little low for S-04.  Seeing how you already had some fermentation and yeast activity at the lower temp, ramping the temp up to 68F or 70F would be fine and I wouldn't expect any flavor issues at this point.  Things should get moving again once the temp is up.

If not once its warmed up (not before)  you could go in with a sanitize racking cane and rouse the yeast too.

Comment: Do you think the S-04 will get through a 1.087 OG cider?